# Was bedeutet "... nimmt die Hürde mit Bravour"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Ich habe gelesen: "Kamerun nimmt die nächste Hürde mit Bravour".

Was bedeutet das (die Hürde nehmen)?

Comment: https://www.dwds.de/wb/H%C3%BCrde#wb-1, number 3

Answer (score 8):

Die Wendung *eine Hürde nehmen* bedeutet

> eine Schwierigkeit überwinden

Eine Hürde stellt beispielsweise im Sport ein Hindernis dar, das zu überwinden ist. Dieser Gedanke wird in der Redensart auch auf andere Hindernisse ausgedehnt. So sind zum Beispiel die Abschlussprüfungen an einer Schule *die letzte Hürde, die zu nehmen ist* (das bedeutet zu überwinden), um den Schulabschluss zu erhalten.

**Ergänzung:** Der OP fragt zwar ausdrücklich nur nach *Hürde nehmen*, der Vollstänigkeit halber noch eine kurze Erläuterung zu *mit Bravour*. Wörtlich bedeutet das Wort "Tapferkeit, Beherztheit, Schneid" und wurde früher meistens im militärischen Bereich genutzt. Im Kontext der Frage wird es im übertragenen Sinn genutzt und bedeutet

> meisterhafte Technik

im Sinne von "meisterhaft ausgeführt".

Comment: Du gehst in deiner Antwort nur auf die Hürde ein, erwähnst aber mit keiner Silbe auf das Wort *Bravour*. Könntest du das noch ergänzen?

Comment: Die Erklärung "meisterhaft ausgeführt" würde nur passen, wenn es etwas auszuführen gab. Falls es sich hier um einen sportlichen Ausscheidungswettkampf handelte, passt "ausgeführt" nicht. Bei einem Mannschaftsspiel könnte es heißen: "gewann(en) das Spiel überlegen und kamen eine Runde weiter" oder "mit einem glanzvollen Sieg gelangten sie ins Viertelfinale" o.ä. Fest steht: Die Kameruner bewältigen auf wirklich vorbildliche und meisterhafte Weise eine schwierige Aufgabe, bei der man nicht unbedingt davon ausgehen konnte, dass sie es schaffen werden.